# How to see the true ending of the game?

Tags: no-more-heroes

I wanted to play again to No More Heroes because apparently I missed the true ending of the game. I remember fighting the final boss and getting rank 1 and that was all, but someone told me there was a real ending for the game. But when I got in my game, I had no idea what to do.

How do you unlock the true ending?

Edit: Following a comment asking for it, I don't have all the katanas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are going to save after getting rank 1, you should have the two following options "Return to Santa Destroy" or "Ending". Just choose the first option, so you can go back before the final battle. There, you need to get all the Beam katanas of the game, which are Tsubaki Mk. I, II, and III. Then go back to the motel to save, and the option "Real Ending" should appear.

Don't worry, you will first see the normal ending playing again. And then you will have the real ending starting (not going to spoil exactly what is happening there, you will discover by yourself).